# adjective list punctutation

Tags: adjectives, punctuation

I wonder if I punctuated the adj order correctly. I think, *steady* and *incompressible* are coordinating adjectives which need a comma between them, however, I am not sure about *three-dimensional*. 
here is the sentence:

"The numerical computation has been performed by solving the steady, incompressible, three-dimensional Reynolds-averaged Navier–Stokes (RANS) equations"

Comment: The commas mark 'coordinated' modification, as you say. In your example "Reynolds-averaged ... equations" is modified by a coordination of adjectives giving the meaning "Reynolds-averaged Navier–Stokes (RANS) equations" that are steady, incompressible and three-dimensional. Omitting the commas would allow a somewhat different interpretation.

Comment: @BillJ thnx. So u would say these two commas between these 3 adjectives are necessary, right?  
like this: "steady, incompressible, and three-dimensional Reynolds-averaged Navier....equations".

Comment: Yes, if the meaning you want to convey is the one that I outlined in my first message.

Answer (score -1):

When a coordinated list functions as a noun or complement, at least one copy of the conjunction is required (between the last two items), and the conjunction may be preceded by an 'Oxford' comma (which helps if there are compound items in the list).

When a list of adjectives restricts a noun phrase, the conjunction 'and' is implicit.  The adjectives should be separated by commas if they could be confused as compound ('hot, pink' vs 'hot pink').

PS: In your question, drop the comma after "I think", and change ", however," to ".  However," or "; however,"  {'however' is not a conjunction}.